# Code First nullable foreign key property

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I would like to know what is the right way to declare 'foreign key' properties on dbcontext. Lets suppose this scenario:

In model:

```
<Display(Name:="IdProduct_fk", Prompt:="IdProduct_fk", Description:=".")> _
<Required(ErrorMessage:="Mandatory")> _
Public Property IdProduct_fk As Integer
Public Property Product As Product
```

Fluent api:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of HI_Conciliacio) _
                .HasRequired(Function(x) x.Product) _
                .WithMany(Function(t) t.MEs) _
                .HasForeignKey(Function(m) m.IdProduct_fk) _
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
```

In this context, `IdProduct_fk` can be defined as `Integer` or as `Integer?`, I think both are valids. My problem is:

1. If property is declared as `Ingeger` it has all time value, also has 0 value on create. This seems dirty for me (or not?)
2. If property is set to `Integer?` then I have not '0' value problem but, value is dropped to Null on remove entity (when I execute ctx.mes.remove( someMeEntity ) ). I need to know its value on savechanges because I do a validate entity on delete (I have overwrote ShouldValidateEntity method on context) and I need to know all foreign key values.

Then, what is the right solution?

Comment: Why does it matter if the value is 0 upon creation? This isn't normally a property you set yourself. You use the navigation properties and set those, which upon saving will automatically populate the value of the foreign key. If you make it nullable in the model, it just means that you can have records in the database that do not have a parent record. This isn't necessarily a bad thing, but if it's not what you are intending then you will have data integrity issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a child (`HI_Conciliacio`) has a required (`Product`) parent (this is how you have defined the relation in the fluent API) then the null or zero value of the foreign key will never be used (or pass a database update), so you can as well use an `Integer` in stead of an `Integer?`.

If you do not use the fluent API declaration then using an `Integer` will signal to the Enity Framework that the relation is required, if it is an `Integer?` then the relation is optional and all child entities that are loaded by the context (!) will have their `ProductId` set to null when the parent Product is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If your Foreign Key can not be null in the database, then it is better to mirror that behavior in your code. Your `.HasRequired()` will ensure that it has always been set.